# How to solve PHP and openssl version difference issue?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I tried to install wardrobe cms via composer but I can't even download composer to start with. I researched and read around but I couldn't come up with a solution. As I understand it it's most likely a SSL issue, specifically OpenSSL with PHP. I'm not familiar with PHP nor OpenSSL, I just wanted to try out wardrobe cms...

As you can see in the output the current installed version of openssl and the version output from php differ. I guess that's my problem. How can I rectify it and finally install wardrobe?

```
~$ sudo apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.2k-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+5
  Candidate: 1.0.2k-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+5
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2k-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+5 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.22 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates/main armhf Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security/main armhf Packages
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main armhf Packages
```

PHP output:

```
~$ php -m | grep openssl
openssl

~$ php -i | grep OpenSSL
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

That's the symptom I experience while trying to install wardrobe cms:

```
~$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an OpenSSL issue, and not just an issue with the networking at the system, or a temporary issue?

Comment: I doubt it's an networking issue because I can download files, update my system, connect to servers etc without any problems.